# Syntax erro at or near "[" shp2pgsql

Tags: postgis, shp2pgsql

I am trying to import a shapefile into my database, but I got a error message when I typed the following command:

*shp2pgsql -I -s 0 /home/IC/Ferramenta_carga/shp/tl_2016_us_state/tl_2016_us_state.shp state | psql -U postgres -d my_database*

Error message:

ERROR: syntax error ar or near "["
LINE 1: [shp2pgsql-core.c:FindPolygons:441] FindPolygons[0]: allocat...

The syntax error appears as much as the number of geometries inside the shapefile.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Please include error messages as text. This makes the message legible on all display devices, and allows search engines to find the question.

Comment: Do you have the .shx and .dbf files kin the same folder? Why don't you specify a valid SRS?